# How to add video in react-native with any format

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video library, but it only supports one format.
just appearing black screen on adding other formats

Answer (score 0):

you can't view any format, but easy way to do is put that video into WebView, then you can use HTML

Comment: can you elaborate Your answer a little more?? what you mean by U?

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean WebView. My computer have font error